# There is an error for email sending using Webmail function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got this error

> The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name:
>   addresses Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'addresses'
>   cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: addresses

I tried all emails but it is not working.

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(Registration reg)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        WebMail.Send(""
                    , reg.Name + "is",
                     reg.Message + "<br></br> My Number : "+reg.Mobile+
   "<br></br> My email is "    +reg.Email
                                    ,null
                                    ,null
                                    ,null       
                                    ,true
                                    ,null
                                    ,null
                                    ,null
                                    ,null
                                    ,null
                                    ,reg.Email);
    }

    return View();
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>  
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
             port="587"         
             userName=""
             password=""
             enableSsl="true"
             />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>      
</system.net>
```

**Contact.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</p>
<p>Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)</p>
<p>Mobile: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mobile)</p>
<p>Message:</p>
<p>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
}
```

even though i put all email, it was not working.

Comment: In your example, the first parameter `to` is an empty string.

Comment: can take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/11-adding-email-to-your-web-site